# Why does std::move() not work without _Remove_reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

_Remove_reference exists for, as you know, converting T& to T or T&& to T.

I made the following code in a playful mood, it doesn't work at all as I expected, but have no idea why.

```
template<class _Ty>
struct _Remove_reference
{   // remove reference
    typedef _Ty _Type;
    static void func(){ cout << "1" << endl; } 
};

// template<class _Ty>
// struct _Remove_reference<_Ty&>
// {    // remove reference
//  typedef _Ty _Type;
//  static void func(){ cout << "2" << endl; }
// };
// 
// template<class _Ty>
// struct _Remove_reference<_Ty&&>
// {    // remove rvalue reference
//  typedef _Ty _Type;
//  static void func(){ cout << "3" << endl; }
// };

template<class _Ty> inline
    typename _Remove_reference<_Ty>::_Type&&
    move(_Ty&& _Arg)
{   // forward _Arg as movable
    typename _Remove_reference<_Ty>::func();
    return ((typename _Remove_reference<_Ty>::_Type&&)_Arg);
}

int main(){
    int a1= 3;
    int&& a2 = move(a1); // can't convert the a1 to int&&
    return 0;
}
```

I guess it's all about reference collapsing rules, and template argument deduction but I am confused. my curiosity about this has to be shattered for me to sleep tight.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given

```
template<class _Ty> inline
typename _Remove_reference<_Ty>::_Type&&
move(_Ty&& _Arg)
```

When you do `move(a1)`, `_Ty` is deduced as `int&`. `_Ty&&` would thus still be `int&` due to the reference collapsing rules, so you need to remove the reference to get `int` before you can make it an rvalue reference.

This is a special case of the template argument deduction rules. If you have a function argument which is `T&&` where `T` is a template parameter, then if you pass an lvalue (i.e. a named object or an lvalue reference) to the function then `T` is deduced as `X&` where `X` is the type of the lvalue object. If you pass an rvalue (a temporary or an rvalue reference) to the function then `T` is just deduced as `X`.

e.g. `move(a1)` deduces `_Ty` to be `int&`, whereas `move(42)` deduces `_Ty` to be `int`.

BTW: I guess you took this code from your compiler's standard library --- names decorated with a leading underscore and a capital letter _Like _This are reserved for the compiler and standard library implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. But wondering why I do need to un-annotate the code? If the purpose of _remove_reference is converting them to T,  why do I need those template specialization verson?

Comment: The specializations are how `_Remove_reference` works. The primary template matches anything, and returns the same type, so `_Remove_reference<int>::type` is just `int`. The partial specializations for references do the reference removal. `_Remove_reference<int&>` matches the first partial specialization, so that is used instead of the primary template. **Within this specialization**, `_Ty` is just `int` (so that `_Ty&` is `int&`), so `_Remove_reference<int&>::type` is a typedef for `int`.

Comment: For the referencing collapsing, see http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html. The entire article, in fact, from page 1, is a good read. Read from the beginning to get the context of things.